# Does Swashbuckle install Swagger UI too?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I installed the latest stable version of Swashbuckle.

It did install the necessary nuget packages & SwaggerConfig.cs. But Swagger UI resources were not installed. Do I need to do that manually by including the [dist] folder in my Web API project?

Answer (score 1):

Swashbuckle comes with a version of swagger-ui. Please see their documentation - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Therefore, once you install swashbuckle, you will have their version of swagger-ui